# LDAP Query only works with (objectclass=*) but not with (objectclass=user)

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm using a PHP Skript to test, if my Query Filter ist correct.
But i can only Query with the filter = "(objectclass=*)" and ii don't know why.

Do you see why?

The PHP Script looks like this:

```
<?php
// basic sequence with LDAP is connect, bind, search, interpret search
// result, close connection

$password = 'myPassword';
$bindDn = 'ldapsync';
$searchDn = 'DC=test,DC=local';
$filter = '(objectClass=*)';
$host = '10.10.10.10';

echo "<h3>LDAP query test</h3>";
echo "Connecting ...";
$ds=ldap_connect($host);  // must be a valid LDAP server!
echo "connect result is " . $ds . "<br />";

if ($ds) { 
   echo "Binding ..."; 
   @ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
   $r=ldap_bind($ds, $bindDn, $password);
   echo "Bind result is " . $r . "<br />";

   echo "Searching for " . $filter . " ..."; // this is a test campusid
   // Search surname entry
   $sr=ldap_search($ds, $searchDn, $filter);  
   echo "Search result is " . $sr . "<br />";

   echo "Number of entires returned is " . ldap_count_entries($ds, $sr) . "<br />";

   echo "Getting entries ...<p>";
   $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
   echo "Data for " . $info["count"] . " items returned:<p>";

   for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
       echo "dn is: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
       echo "first cn entry is: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
       //echo "first type is: " . $info[$i]["type"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
   }

   echo "Closing connection";
   ldap_close($ds);

} else {
   echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server</h4>";
}
?>
```

The Error i get is:
[image: working]

[image: not working]

Comment: Are you sure `objectClass` is really `user` in your ldap directory ? It generally sounds more like `inetOrgPerson`, `inetUser`, `person`, `posixAccount` ...

Comment: Sorry, this was not on m agenda for a while. I testet your input, but it seems it is a user (and person etc.) but none of those objectclasses work on my filter. Is that maybe a general problem?